# Bluetooth OPP profile - 'Client proxy not available'

Tags: linux, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, obex, bluetooth-profile

I'm trying to enable the bluetooth OPP profile in my linux machine(Ubuntu-16.04 LTS) to connect it with android phone.

- Initially I enabled the bluetooth interface using the command, `/etc/init.d/bluetooth start`
- Began to scan for the devices to connect, using the `hcitool scan` that displays both device 'Bluetooth MAC address and Username'
- I paired my PC with the device (Redmi note 4-Android Nougat) using the command `hcitool cc --role=s <br_addr>`
- Then I executed the command the `sudo obexctl`, which lead to the interactive mode,
  `[obex]# connect <br_addr>`

On connecting to the device using its bluetooth MAC address, following error is thrown,

`Client proxy not available`

Hope this link would be useful as it explains what the exact output is supposed to be like.
https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/bluetooth/bluez/docs/reference/sending-files

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I just now figured out the answer for my own question(thought to leave the question undeleted as it may help someone encountering the same situation)

Before intialising the bluetooth services, got to run the daemon,

`sudo service bluetooth stop
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo service bluetooth start
sudo hciconfig -a hci0 reset`

So now good to go, the obexctl command can be executed. Once entered into the interactive mode, connections can be made and the file could be pushed or pulled as mentioned in the link.

Comment: Why did you run `systemctl daemon-reload`?